# CrashLytics Android integration issue

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, jenkins, crashlytics

I have an Android app that, when built on my development machine with CrashLytics being used, the application runs fine. However, if I have CrashLytics in my application and use Jenkins with Ant to build the app (Jenkins is on a different machine), the app **when launched** will immediately crash. No CrashLytics report is generated. These are the scenarios I've tried:

### Works (Doesn't crash when launched)

- Built via Eclipse on my development machine with CrashLytics being used.
- Built via Eclipse on my development machine without CrashLytics being used.
- Built via Ant on my development machine with CrashLytics being used.
- Built via Ant on my development machine without CrashLytics being used.
- Built via Jenkins (Ant) on my CI machine without CrashLytics being used.

### Doesn't Work (Crashes when launched)

- Built via Jenkins (Ant) on my CI machine with CrashLytics being used.

So, I'm doubting it has to do with my Ant configuration as it works on the development machine with the same Ant build.xml.

**Any ideas why putting CrashLytics into the software would cause it to crash, but only on a non-development machine?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you installed Crashlytics on your development machine it was probably installed to do its custom build steps only when you build through Eclipse. The reason it works when you build using Ant on your development machine is that some of those steps have already been performed on this machine.

You need to add the Crashlytics Ant build steps as described at http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/203395-ant

Comment: Having issue even after following the steps described. here are my imports in build.xml  
 `<!-- version-tag: custom -->
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
    <import file="../crashalytics-devtools/custom_rules.xml" />`